# PVC drain pipe that the washer empties into is echoing all plumbing sounds

Tags: plumbing, drain, drain-waste-vent, washer

My father said that we could put tape around the washer hose to lessen the gap between the hose and the pipe. I've found some adapters that go from the ~1" washer hose to our 2" pipe. My father said though to leave a little bit of a gap between each hose, while the adapters I've found online seem to completely seal the connection. Which is correct? Should I leave an air gap or completely seal it?

EDIT: The house was built in 1952. Based on my understanding, the plumbing should look like this:

[image: Plumbing drain layout & direction]

NOTE: Periodic gurgling occurs in the bath drain if the bath hasn't been used in a couple of days. We believe this is because the vents are blocked to some extent, and get flushed out after showers, but then settles after a while.

EDIT 2: This home is a rental, we do not own it; not sure if that matters in your comments.

Comment: That somewhat depends on whether there's an adjacent vent in the plumbing, or if you have old-school plumbing that would bind up without venting at the inlet. Please edit to provide more information about your home's plumbing.

Comment: I have made that mistake in the past 1940's home ended up causing a leak at the pump.

Comment: if you hear plumbing sounds, then there is no trap ... sewer gas can enter your house

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't, you should have installed a trap in that drain line to keep noise and smells from coming up the line. Make sure it is low enough to have a good amount of drain pipe above the trap so when the washer drains the water does not overflow from the pipe. If the drain will be inside the wall make sure you use a glued trap so no joint will come loose at a later time.

Comment: I don't think this is an issue. The pipe is completely accessible next to the washer and extends roughly 36" from the floor and I'm assuming there is a trap in the PVC under the house. The washer drain pipe comes up from the bottom of the washer and hangs over into the PVC drain pipe.

Comment: Allow me to ask you a question; Why don't you need a trap on this appliance when there is a trap on every other sink, bathtub, shower, etc. in the house. Yes you need a trap for the washer drain, and you should not try to close off the rest of the drain with tape or other adapters. The rest of the pipe opening acts as a vent when the washer is draining

Comment: No no no, I believe there is a trap on the pipe. That was why I said that I didn't think it was an issue. I'm well aware of the need for a trap on each drain pipe. As far as the vent goes, there's a vent between the washer drain pipe and the exit pipe to the road, so does the drain pipe need to vent the washer drain?